# Document when workbook last edited

Tags: excel, vba

I found code in a book:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveAndCLose()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Tabelle1.Range("A1").Value = _
    "Last Edition " & Now & " from User " & Environ("Username")
    ThisWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Is it possible to document the last 10 edits. For example: today USER X edited - `Range("A1")`. Next day there was another edit made `Range("A2")` and so on for each edition for that file.

I know that in Excel Audit Trail isn't implemented but that simple code gives information who made the last edit.

Or maybe there is a better way to implement an Audit Trail for Excel files?

Comment: Yesm should be possible, What did you try so far in order to adapt the code you found in one of your books to your needs?

Comment: Once you have ten rows, simply delete the first and add value at row ten...

Comment: Excel has **built-in features** for tracking changes to shared workbooks.  See [**here**](https://www.google.com/search?q=track+changes+excel) for more info.

Comment: But with the disadvantage it becomes a shared workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward simple code might be the following code

```
Option Explicit
Const X = "X"

Sub SaveAndClose()

Dim rgB As Range
Dim rowX As Long
Dim auditTxt As String

    Set rgB = Tabelle1.Range("B1:B10")
    auditTxt = "Last Edition " & Now & " from User " & Environ("Username")

    rowX = findXA(rgB)
    'rowX = findX(rgB)

    If rowX = 0 Then
        Tabelle1.Cells(1, 1).Value = auditTxt
        Tabelle1.Cells(1, 2).Value = X
    ElseIf rowX = 10 Then
        Tabelle1.Cells(1, 1).Value = auditTxt
        Tabelle1.Cells(1, 2).Value = X
        Tabelle1.Cells(rowX, 2).ClearContents
    Else
        Tabelle1.Cells(rowX + 1, 1).Value = auditTxt
        Tabelle1.Cells(rowX + 1, 2).Value = X
        Tabelle1.Cells(rowX, 2).ClearContents
    End If


    ''    I commented this part of the code for testing purposes
    ''    Uncomment to save and close the file

    '    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    '    ThisWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True
    '    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
Function findX(rg As Range) As Long
' find the X by putting the range into an array and looping through it
    Dim vDat As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    findX = 0
    vDat = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rg)

    For i = LBound(vDat) To UBound(vDat)
        If UCase(vDat(i)) = X Then
            findX = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

Function findXA(rg As Range) As Long
' find the X by usind ragne.find
Dim rgX As Range

    Set rgX = rg.Find(X, , , , , , False)
    If rgX Is Nothing Then
        findXA = 0
    Else
        findXA = rgX.Row
    End If

End Function
```

Code uses col A and B and it put an X into col B for the last written line. Maybe it is not a "clever" code but IMO it is just easy to follow, I hope
[image]

Comment: Wow, i was trying some things, but what you did is pretty clever. Thank you for your help

Comment: I decided to put in as BeforeClose command. That code there was started 2 times. Changed      ThisWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True to ThisWorkbook.Saved = True. Thanks once again!